# Delayed push notification on Android phone

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, push-notification

I am facing delayed notification when phone is ideal and not in use for few minutes. Even sometimes I am getting notification when phone start to use, not before that. Is it app issue or phone settings issue? I tried to change phone settings like Turn Off Adaptive Battery, Don’t Optimize for that app. I checked app side; I didn’t find anything wrong from app.  Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to set the priority of the messages from the backend to high priority.

Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, maybe you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem when I added a special http header: urgency-option

See more: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8030#section-5.3